# Word for the sacred limit of ancient Greek temple?

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a special word for the boundaries or limits of the sacred area of an ancient Greek temple. It is "tenemon" or "termina" or "telemon" or something like that. Does anyone remember?

Answer (score 2):

I found it by some judicious Googling: [*temenos*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temenos).